# Pyparsing - grammar with recursion

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to create grammar which will parse the following expressions:

1. `func()`
2. `func(a)`
3. `func(a) + func(b)`
4. `func(func(a) + func()) + func(b)`

I implemented it for (1) and (2), but once I extended `rvalue << (identifier | function_call)` by `operation`, it stopped working due to:

```
Exception raised:Expected W:(ABCD...), found ')'  (at char 5), (line:1, col:6)
Exception raised:maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Can anyone of you explain why? As far as I understood in expression `rvalue << (identifier | function_call | operation)`  `function_call` should be matched before `operation` and the recursion shouldn't take place.

**Code:**

```
from pyparsing import Forward, Optional, Word, Literal, alphanums, delimitedList

rvalue = Forward()

operation = rvalue + Literal('+') + rvalue
identifier = Word(alphanums + '_')('identifier')
function_args = delimitedList(rvalue)('function_args')

function_name = identifier('function_name')
function_call = (
    (function_name + Literal("(") + Optional(function_args) + Literal(")"))
)('function_call')

rvalue << (identifier | function_call | operation)
function_call.setDebug()


def test_function_call_no_args():
    bdict = function_call.parseString("func()", parseAll=True).asDict()
    assert bdict['function_name'] == 'func'
    assert 'function_args' not in bdict


def test_function_call_one_arg():
    bdict = function_call.parseString("func(arg)", parseAll=True).asDict()
    assert bdict['function_name'] == 'func'
    assert 'function_args' in bdict


def test_function_call_many_args():
    bdict = function_call.parseString("func(arg1, arg2)", parseAll=True).asDict()
    assert bdict['function_name'] == 'func'
    assert 'function_args' in bdict
```

Comment: Is something like `func(a + b)` also valid?

Comment: Write a BNF for your little parser and look for left-recursion. Note that '|' means "MatchFirst", not "MatchLongest", so parsing for identifier before function will generally be a problem (you'll match the identifier, and then you'll be at '(' and the parser will go "huh?").  Hint: this is left recursive:  `rvalue ::= rvalue '+' rvalue`.

Comment: This is difficult because `function_call` starts with an `identifier` and pyparsing doesn't do backtracking, so it's impossible for pyparsing to distinguish between an `identifier` and a `function_call` - we can never use an alternation like `identifier | function_call` or `function_call | identifier` because pyparsing will never even attempt to parse the right-hand side.

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes, good spot, `func(a + b)` is also valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understood in expression `rvalue << (identifier | function_call | operation)` function_call should be matched before operation and the recursion shouldn't take place.

The recursion doesn't take place if one of the previous alternatives succeeds. But if both fail, `operation` is tried and you get infinite recursion.

For example, in `test_function_call_no_args` you try to parse `func()` using the `function_call` rule. This will parse `func` as the name of the function and `(` as the beginning of the argument list. Then it will try to parse `Optional(function_args)`, which will in turn try to parse `delimitedList(rvalue)`. Now this will try to parse `rvalue` and since `)` doesn't match the first two alternatives, it will try the last one, which will cause the infinite recursion.

When a rule is recursive, you must always consume input before the recursion is reached - it must not be possible to reach the recursion without consuming input. So having the recursion come last in an alternative isn't enough - there must actually be another non-optional rule (that also doesn't match the empty string) be successfully invoked before it.

PS: `rvalue` as it is can actually never match a function call because function calls start with an identifier and you match `identifier` first.

Comment: "The recursion doesn't take place if one of the previous alternatives succeeds. But if both fail, operation is tried and you get infinite recursion."

Without `operation` code passes unit tests, which means that alternatives succeed, so I wonder what exactly changes `operation` in this line.

Comment: @gbajson "Without operation code passes unit tests, which means that alternatives succeed" No, it doesn't mean that. When `rvalue` is matched inside `()`, the first two alternatives will fail as they should. And without the recursive rule invocation, everything would be fine: both alternatives will fail, so the whole rule fails and thus the parser knows that there are no arguments and it moves on. But once you add the recursive invocation as the third alternative, it no longer fails properly, but goes into the infinite recursion instead and that's why things break.